# How to draw this Venn Diagram using PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, text-manipulation

[image]

The code I wrote for it is -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\pscircle(-3,-3){6}
\pscircle(5,-3){6}
\put(-6,-3){$\text{multiples\ of\  2}$}
\put(5.5,-3){$\text{multiples\ of\  3}$}
\put(-1,-3){$\text{multiples of 6}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

for which the output I am getting is-

[image]

You see the problem right?

First I cannot seem to stack the words `multiples` and `of 2` over each other like that. and also, how in the world I shade this specific area. I know how to shade the whole circle i.e. by putting `[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray]` after `\pscircle` when making the circle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could only reproduce your output after setting `unit` to 0.5cm. Anyway, this code produces something close to your desired picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\pscircle(-3,-3){6}
\pscircle(5,-3){6}
\rput[c](-4,-3){\begin{tabular}{c}multiples\\ of 2
\end{tabular}}
\rput[c](6,-3){\begin{tabular}{c}
multiples\\ of 3
\end{tabular}
}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray, linestyle=solid]{
    \psarc(-3,-3){6}{-48}{48}
    \psarc(5,-3){6}{132}{228}
    }
\rput[c](1,-3){\begin{tabular}{c}
multiples\\ of 6
\end{tabular}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd also recommend to use the `pstricks` command `\rput` instead of `\put`.

Comment: what is the difference between `\rput` and `\put`?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth "r" is for "relative".

Comment: @marmot so we have to compute manually -48, 48 and 132 , 228. Is there a trick to get these values automatically?

Comment: @pzorba75 see Herbert 's post below. Notice that one does not have to compute the angles precisely, though. If you put, say, -60 instead of -48, it also works.

Comment: @marmot when did you start coming into `pstricks` territory?

Comment: @marmot Huhh, good to know!! Well I thought your primary focus was only on `TikZ`.

Answer (score 7):

Use clipping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6,-3)(6,3)
    \rput(-2.5,0){\shortstack{multiples\\of 2}}
    \rput(2.5,0){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 3}}
    \psclip{\pscircle(-2,0){3}}
        \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray](2,0){3}
    \endpsclip
    \pscircle(2,0){3}
    \rput(0,0){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 6}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer `\pscustom`, then use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-6,-3)(6,3)
\pstGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](-2,0){A}(2,0){B}
\pstInterCC[RadiusA=\pstDistVal{3},RadiusB=\pstDistVal{3}]{A}{}{B}{}{I1}{I2}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!30]{%
  \pstArcOAB{A}{I2}{I1}
  \pstArcOAB{B}{I1}{I2}
}
\pscircle(A){3}\pscircle(B){3}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use pst-eucl.

[image]

```
\documentclass[svgnames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-9,-6)(11,6)
\pnode(-3,0){A}
\pnode(5,0){B}
\midAB(A)(B){M}
\def\radA{6}
\def\radB{6}
\pscircle(A){\radA}
\pscircle(B){\radB}
\rput[r](A){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 2}}
\rput[l](B){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 3}}
\pstInterCC[DistCoef=1, RadiusA=\pstDistVal{\radA},DistCoef=1,
                  RadiusB=\pstDistVal{\radB}]{A}{}{B}{}{E}{F}%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray, linestyle=solid]{
    \pstArcOAB{A}{F}{E}
    \pstArcOAB{B}{E}{F}
    }
\rput[c](M){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 6}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If it is necessary to calculate the angles, this can be done on the postscript-side:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm,x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,saveNodeCoors,NodeCoorPrefix=n](-9,-6)(11,6)
\pnodes(-3,0){A}(5,0){B}
\midAB(A)(B){M}
\def\radA{6}
\def\radB{6}
\pscircle(A){\radA}
\pscircle(B){\radB}
\rput[r](A){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 2}}
\rput[l](B){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 3}}
\pstInterCC[RadiusA=\pstDistVal{\radA},RadiusB=\pstDistVal{\radB}]{A}{}{B}{}{E}{F}%
\pnode(F){Fq}\pnode(E){Eq}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=solid]{
  \psarc(A){\radA}{! nFqy nAy sub nFqx nAx sub atan}{! nEqy nAy sub nEqx nAx sub atan}
  \psarc(B){\radB}{! nEqy nBy sub nEqx nBx sub atan}{! nFqy nBy sub nFqx nBx sub atan}
  }
\rput[c](M){\shortstack{multiples\\ of 6}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert do you know why the nodes E and F are not working with saveNodeCoors?

Comment: `\pstArcOAB{A}{E}{F}` No need for calculating anything.

Comment: `pst-eucl` handles its own nodes in a different way. The reason why `SaveNodeCoors` doesn't work.

Comment: @Herbert Okay I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), wrapped up here in [luamplib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en), (so compile this with `lualatex`, or adapt it for [GMP](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en) or plain MP).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\def\stack#1{\hbox{\vbox{\let\\\cr\halign{\hss##\hss\cr#1\crcr}}}}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path twos, threes, sixes;

    twos = fullcircle scaled 144 rotated 180 shifted 42 left;
    threes = fullcircle scaled 144           shifted 42 right;
    sixes = buildcycle(twos, threes);

    fill twos   withcolor 3/4[red, white];
    fill threes withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
    fill sixes  withcolor 3/4[1/2 red + 1/2 blue, white];

    draw twos;
    draw threes;

    label("\stack{multiples\\of 2}", center twos shifted 20 left);
    label("\stack{multiples\\of 3}", center threes shifted 20 right);
    label("\stack{multiples\\of 6}", center sixes);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Note

- The hard work of finding the overlap is done by the `buildcycle` macro, that finds the overlapping area of one or more paths.  There's a small bug (or at least a feature) of this macro that if you use it with only two paths, and if both paths are cyclic (ie closed), then the starting point of one must not be inside the other one.

The built-in path `fullcircle` starts at 3 o'clock (as it were), so to get `buildcycle` to work with two `fullcircle`s you need to rotate one or both of them so that these points do not lie inside each other.  This is why I used `rotated 180` in the definition of the `twos` path.

Answer (score 1):

With the new `oefill` (odd-even rule) option.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}    
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(5,3)
\pscustom[fillstyle=oefill,fillcolor=lightgray]{\pscircle(-2,0){3}\pscircle(2,0){3}}
\foreach \x/\y/\t in {-3/0/2,0/0/6,3/0/3}{\rput(\x,\y){\shortstack{multiples\\ of \t}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Warning

The red frame is added to show there is a small bug in `oefill` option. Can you see an extra white space on the left? Also note that `oefill` sets weirdly "multiples of 2" and "multiples of 3" regions to opaque.

Comment: The extra trailing space has been removed by Herbert.